# Can I keep robots.txt in a contextpath and give a 301 redirect?

Tags: http-status-code-301, robots.txt

My website uses a contextpath (eg: www.example.com/abc). The robots.txt is available at www.example.com/abc/robots.txt and I have given a 301 redirect in webserver to redirect www.example.com/robots.txt to www.example.com/abc/robots.txt.

My question is whether the search engines be able to read the robots.txt file since it has a 301 redirect?

Answer (score 1):

Found that the search engines are honoring the 301 redirect and reading the file from the subfolder.

Comment: I observe the same. It seems Google Search Console tool https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool does not complain.

Answer (score 0):

Robots.txt should be on root level

```
https://example.com/robots.txt - Correct
https://blog.example.com/robots.txt - Correct
https://example.com/abc/robots.txt - Not Correct
https://blog.example.com/abc/robots.txt - Not Correct
```

If it is on sub directory/sub folder then it will return 404 error(Because they make calls only on root directory), and [Google will ignore your robots.txt completely if it is return 301 or 404 error.](https://twitter.com/methode/status/832209459967619072)